# Inner product vs. vector triad form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

This program involves the matrix-vector computational primitive $y \leftarrow Ax$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. A is taken to be dense and banded in the two parts of the problem. Recall, there are many ways to implement the primitive. Two standard approaches are: 
$$\eta_i = e_i^{T}y = e_i^{T}Ax = \tilde{a}_i^{T}x, 1\leq i\leq n \ \ \text{inner product form}$$

$$y = \sum_{1}^{n}(Ae_i)(e_i^{T}x) = \sum_{1}^{n}a_i\xi_i, \ \ \text{vector triad form}$$

Note: $e^T$ is the standard basis vector.

I know that when implemented these two approaches will produce the same result but I do not understand what the two forms are doing. I believe the inner product form is just multiplying every value in each row of $A$ to the values in $x$ and summing. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, I will be programming these in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many different ways to do matrix vector multiplication or the more general matrix matrix multiplication. Mathematically, they return the same result, but their run times differs significantly depending on the size and type of the relevant matrices as well as details of the underlying architeture. The goal is acheive an implementation which minimizes the runtime by making the best possible use of the available resources.

You mention two different ways of computing the matrix vector product $y = Ax$.  Let us assume that matrix is $n$ by $n$ for the sake of simplicity. Let $r_i$ denote the $i$th row vector of $A$ and let $c_j$ denote the $j$ th column vector. Then
\begin{equation}
y = Ax = (r_1 \cdot x, r_2 \cdot x, \dotsc, r_n \cdot x)^T = \sum_{j=1}^n c_j x_j.
\end{equation}
The first method access the matrix $A$by rows, whereas the second method access the matrix by columns. The performance of the method depends on how the matrix is stored. In Fortran matrices are stored by columns by default. This is called column major format. This format favors the second method because it ensures that the matrix is accessed with stride $1$. This reduces the number of cache misses and improves performance. If the first method is used for a matrix in column major format, then the matrix would be accessed with stride $n$. This would dramatically increase the number of cache misses and significantly reduce the rate at which flops can be executed. Many C programmers prefer to store their matrices by rows, using an array of pointers to point to the beginning of each row. Here the situation is reversed. One should at all times use an algorithm which is compatible with the memory layout.

Banded matrices are normally stored in a special format, imaginatively called banded format. This is implemented in LAPACK and described here http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node124.html. This format compresses the matrix into a wide rectangle which allow the columns to be accessed with stride 1. The corresponding matrix vector multiplication routine is called DGBMV (Double precision General Band Matrix Vector multiplication) and is documented here http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d3f/dgbmv_8f_source.html. In reality, the routine is nothing but a special case of the second method which takes the unique sparsity patterns of the matrix into account.

Comment: Ok, just to make sure that I understand. For the first method (inner product) I take the rows of $A$ and multiply by the elements of $x$. And for the second I take the columns of $A$ and multiply by the elements of $x$?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. This is precisely how you should view the two methods.

Comment: by the way do you code in C++?

Comment: No, I get by C and Fortran 95 as needed and develop ideas in MATLAB. I only need a small subset of these languages.

Comment: I see I assume your doing a PhD in computational mathematics?

Comment: Close, but those days are behind me :) I finished my Ph.D. in mathematics some years ago, but my specialization was certainly in computational science.

Comment: nice I am first year PhD in financial mathematics. Thanks again for your help, your a boss!

Comment: Good luck with your studies and remember to do something else as well :)

Comment: Indeed, thank you I do just this course in computational mathematics is really hard. If you do tutoring by the way I could totally use one for this class come test time. I assume your not in the states so we could skype if your interested not sure if you have the time

Comment: I am sorry to turn you down, but I do not have the time. I have considerable commitments both to local students and two different research projects. The time that I spend on MSE goes out of my spare time which is in short supply already.

Comment: ok, no problem just thought I would ask good luck with your research projects